# Adding graphics to components created at runtime

Tags: c#

For anybody that can help me out here I'd be very grateful!

I've got a very small app which creates several panels at runtime with a for LOOP. At the moment the number of panels to be created is derived from a value entered in a textbox, but will ultimately be determined by an integer read from a database

Each panel has a Label which is created in the same loop

My problem is that I want to draw 120 lines in each panel as it is created (in each iteration of the FOR loop), and I'm doing this with a nested WHILE loop

I can get everything to work fine, the panels are creating along with the Label titles, but for some reason I can't get the lines to draw

It's all in one method for testing, can anybody help me?

The code I currently have is as follows:

```
public void CreatePanels()
{
    int PanelPosX = 50;
    int PanelPosY = 500;
    int LabelPosX = 10;
    int LabelPosY = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < (Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text)); i++)
    {
        Panel pnlOverview = new Panel();
        pnlOverview.Name = "InspectorPanel" + i.ToString();
        pnlOverview.Text = "Inspector Panel " + i.ToString();
        pnlOverview.Location = new Point(PanelPosX, PanelPosY);
        pnlOverview.Size = new Size(974, 136);
        pnlOverview.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        Controls.Add(pnlOverview);
        PanelPosY += 170;

        Label lblInspectorName = new Label();
        lblInspectorName.Name = "InspectorName" + i.ToString();
        lblInspectorName.Text = " Inspector " + i.ToString();
        lblInspectorName.Width = 100;
        lblInspectorName.Height = 13;
        lblInspectorName.Location = new Point(LabelPosX, LabelPosY);
        lblInspectorName.Size = new Size(974, 136);
        pnlOverview.Controls.Add(lblInspectorName);

        // Draw the Overview Chart

        int x = 10;
        int y = 0;

        Pen OVTable = new Pen(Color.Black, 0);

        while (y < 120)
        {
            Graphics mp = pnlOverview.CreateGraphics();
            mp.DrawLine(OVTable, x, 40, x, 100);
            y++;
            x += 8;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Thanks
Ivan

Answer (score 0):

You might need to create an empty Image and draw into it and then add it to the Panel. The other option would be to Derive from Panel and override the OnPaint method, at which point you would draw your chart.

Perhaps there is a C# Chart component that would effect this for you.

Here's a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxys6ytf%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to a MSDN reference on rendering custom controls, which is what you are pursuing.